# For what values of a does this sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Say $a > 0$ and $z(1)>0$. Let a sequence be defined recursively by 
$$
z(n+1) = (a + z(n))^{1/2}\text{ for }n \ge 1.
$$
I know the theorem if a sequence is monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing and bounded then it converges.
I tried to use induction on the sequence to check if it's going to increase or decrease monotonically and under what values of a . (But failed miserably).
Can someone provide a hint to the way such a problem is solved ?
Thanks

Comment: Try finding out what value of $z(n)$ is such that $z(n+1)=z(n)$.

Comment: @RushabhMehta I found out  a relation between Z(n) and "a" such that Z(n+1) will be equal to Z(n). What next ?

Comment: And what did you find it to be

Comment: (1+sqrt(1+4a))/2 and (1-sqrt(1+4a))/2

Comment: So now check what happens when $a$ is above and below both of these values.

Comment: Well If z(n)  has value greater than these two roots then the difference (between z(n+1) and z(n)) is positive. Same goes if z(n) has values below both the roots. Does than mean that only for finite number of values of n the sequence is decreasing for a fixed value of a ?

Comment: if we name $c = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$ is the positive root, how does $(z_{n+1} - c)^2$ compare to $(z_{n} - c)^2 \; \; ?$ Same question for the absolute values, meaning the square roots of the above squares

Comment: a little cleaner: how does $|z_{n+1}^2 - c^2|$ compare with $|z_{n}^2 - c^2| \; \; ? \; \;$

Comment: this also matters. We are told $a>0.$ How big is $c \; \; ? \; \; $